# Spring boot applications high availability

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, high-availability

We have a microservice which is developed using spring boot. couple of the functionalities it implements is

1) A scheduler that triggers, at a specified time,  a file download using webhdfs and process it and once the data is processed, it will send an email to users with the data process summary.
2) Read messages from kafka and once the data is read, send an email to users.

We are now planning to make this application high available either in Active-Active or Active-passive set up. The problem we are facing now is if both the instances of the application are running then both of them will try to download the file/read the data from kafka, process it and send emails.  How can this be avoided? I mean to ensure that only one instance triggers the download and process it ?

Please let me know if there is known solution for this kind of scenarios as this seems to be a common scenario in most of the projects? Is master-slave/leader election approach a correct solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let the service download that file, extract the information and publish them via kafka.
Check beforehand if the information was already processed by querying kafka or a local DB.

You also could publish an `DataProcessed`-Event that triggers the `EmailService`, that sends the corresponding E-Mail.